# Hp ProBook stuck at boot logo Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bios

I have an HP ProBook running Windows 10.

Suddenly  Windows won't startup and the boot up stops at HP logo.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

First, check your BIOS if the hard disk Windows 10 is installed on is the first boot priority. If it is, and still doesn't boot, try resetting the BIOS to it's factory defaults (and make sure the hard disk with Windows 10 still is the first boot priority afterwards), maybe you disabled some important feature required for boot.

If that doesn't help, you should try and use the Windows 10 recovery. There are many options to do this, the easiest is to insert your installation media (e.g. a USB drive or DVD that came with your computer, or a USB drive or DVD you bought Windows on), and boot from it (make it temporarily the first boot priority in BIOS).

In case you don't have your installation media anymore, you can create a new one at the [Windows 10 ISO download site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). Grab the ISO image from there, and burn it to a DVD, or copy it's content onto a USB drive. You can also search for "create a recovery device" on another working Windows 10 computer. Furthermore, there might be a recovery partition on your hard disk, so you might try to boot that using the BIOS or by pressing some recovery key on your keyboard, check your manual for that.

When you started your computer in recovery mode using either your installation media, a recovery device or a recovery partition, you have to enter some settings like language, and then select "Repair your computer". Windows will offer you multiple options to do so. Refer to [this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options) for further information. (There are search engines on the internet, use them!)

If you can't manage to boot a recovery device, maybe your hardware is faulty. In that case, consider calling HP support.